# Bind SecurePassword to ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I try to bind the `SecurePassword` property of a `PasswordBox` to my `ViewModel` with a custom `Behavior`. Sadly it doesn't work properly.

Basically I added a property to the `Behavior` which contains the target property of my `ViewModel`.

Any ideas why it doesn't work?

PS: I am currently on the way home without my laptop, I gonna update the question with my code in about 15 minutes. But would be nice if someone would post ideas or sth.

**EDIT**

As I promised, here is some code :)

The `Behavior` first:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Interactivity;
using System.Security;

namespace Knerd.Behaviors {
    public class PasswordChangedBehavior : Behavior<PasswordBox> {

        protected override void OnAttached() {
            AssociatedObject.PasswordChanged += AssociatedObject_PasswordChanged;
            base.OnAttached();
        }

        private void AssociatedObject_PasswordChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            if (AssociatedObject.Password != null)
                TargetPassword = AssociatedObject.SecurePassword;
        }

        protected override void OnDetaching() {
            AssociatedObject.PasswordChanged -= AssociatedObject_PasswordChanged;
            base.OnDetaching();
        }

        public SecureString TargetPassword {
            get { return (SecureString)GetValue(TargetPasswordProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TargetPasswordProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for TargetPassword.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TargetPasswordProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("TargetPassword", typeof(SecureString), typeof(PasswordChangedBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(default(SecureString)));
    }
}
```

The `PasswordBox`:

```
<PasswordBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="5" Width="300" MinWidth="200">
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <behaviors:PasswordChangedBehavior TargetPassword="{Binding Password}" />
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</PasswordBox>
```

And last, the part of my `ViewModel`.

```
private SecureString password;

public SecureString Password {
    get { return password; }
    set {
        if (password != value) {
            password = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Password");
        }
    }
}
```

I hope anyone can help, atm I use the codebehind version but I rather wouldn't.

**EDIT 2**

What actually doesn't work is, that the `TargetPassword` property doesn't update the property of my `ViewModel`

Comment: Some code of your behavior would help to understand your issue ;)

Comment: I hope he is on schedule

Comment: Like I said, in about 10 minutes :)

Comment: @Didier The code is added guys ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found a kinda weird solution. Please improve if there is sth to improve :)

I just changed it like so:

The `Behavior`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Interactivity;
using System.Security;

namespace Knerd.Behaviors {
    public class PasswordChangedBehavior : Behavior<PasswordBox> {

        protected override void OnAttached() {
            AssociatedObject.PasswordChanged += AssociatedObject_PasswordChanged;
            base.OnAttached();
        }

        private void AssociatedObject_PasswordChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            if (AssociatedObject.SecurePassword != null)
                AssociatedObject.DataContext = AssociatedObject.SecurePassword.Copy();
        }

        protected override void OnDetaching() {
            AssociatedObject.PasswordChanged -= AssociatedObject_PasswordChanged;
            base.OnDetaching();
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for TargetPassword.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TargetPasswordProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("TargetPassword", typeof(SecureString), typeof(PasswordChangedBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(default(SecureString)));
    }
}
```

The `ViewModel` didn't change at all, but here is my `View`:

```
<PasswordBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="5" Width="300" MinWidth="200" DataContext="{Binding Password, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <behaviors:PasswordChangedBehavior />
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</PasswordBox>
```

That works just perfect, without exposing the plaintext password.

Answer (score 2):

Create an attach property

```
public static class PasswordBoxAssistant
{
 public static readonly DependencyProperty BoundPassword =
      DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("BoundPassword", typeof(string), typeof(PasswordBoxAssistant), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty, OnBoundPasswordChanged));

  public static readonly DependencyProperty BindPassword = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
      "BindPassword", typeof (bool), typeof (PasswordBoxAssistant), new PropertyMetadata(false, OnBindPasswordChanged));


  private static readonly DependencyProperty UpdatingPassword =
      DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("UpdatingPassword", typeof(bool), typeof(PasswordBoxAssistant), new PropertyMetadata(false));

  private static void OnBoundPasswordChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {
      PasswordBox box = d as PasswordBox;

      // only handle this event when the property is attached to a PasswordBox
      // and when the BindPassword attached property has been set to true
      if (d == null || !GetBindPassword(d))
      {
          return;
      }

      // avoid recursive updating by ignoring the box's changed event
      box.PasswordChanged -= HandlePasswordChanged;

      string newPassword = (string)e.NewValue;

      if (!GetUpdatingPassword(box))
      {
          box.Password = newPassword;
      }

      box.PasswordChanged += HandlePasswordChanged;
  }

  private static void OnBindPasswordChanged(DependencyObject dp, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {
      // when the BindPassword attached property is set on a PasswordBox,
      // start listening to its PasswordChanged event

      PasswordBox box = dp as PasswordBox;

      if (box == null)
      {
          return;
      }

      bool wasBound = (bool)(e.OldValue);
      bool needToBind = (bool)(e.NewValue);

      if (wasBound)
      {
          box.PasswordChanged -= HandlePasswordChanged;
      }

      if (needToBind)
      {
          box.PasswordChanged += HandlePasswordChanged;
      }
  }

  private static void HandlePasswordChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
      PasswordBox box = sender as PasswordBox;

      // set a flag to indicate that we're updating the password
      SetUpdatingPassword(box, true);
      // push the new password into the BoundPassword property
      SetBoundPassword(box, box.Password);
      SetUpdatingPassword(box, false);
  }

  public static void SetBindPassword(DependencyObject dp, bool value)
  {
      dp.SetValue(BindPassword, value);
  }

  public static bool GetBindPassword(DependencyObject dp)
  {
      return (bool)dp.GetValue(BindPassword);
  }

  public static string GetBoundPassword(DependencyObject dp)
  {
      return (string)dp.GetValue(BoundPassword);
  }

  public static void SetBoundPassword(DependencyObject dp, string value)
  {
      dp.SetValue(BoundPassword, value);
  }

  private static bool GetUpdatingPassword(DependencyObject dp)
  {
      return (bool)dp.GetValue(UpdatingPassword);
  }

  private static void SetUpdatingPassword(DependencyObject dp, bool value)
  {
      dp.SetValue(UpdatingPassword, value);
  }
}
```

And in your `XAML`

```
<Page xmlns:ff="clr-namespace:FunctionalFun.UI">
<!-- [Snip] -->
  <PasswordBox x:Name="PasswordBox"
      ff:PasswordBoxAssistant.BindPassword="true"  ff:PasswordBoxAssistant.BoundPassword="{Binding Path=Password, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">

</Page>
```

You probably don't want to do this anyway but if you really want to go ahead.

> The reason the WPF/Silverlight PasswordBox doesn't expose a DP for the Password property is security related.
>   If WPF/Silverlight were to keep a DP for Password it would require the framework to keep the password itself unencrypted in memory. Which is considered quite a troublesome security attack vector. The PasswordBox uses encrypted memory (of sorts) and the only way to access the password is through the CLR property.

I would suggest that when accessing the PasswordBox.Password CLR property you'd refrain from placing it in any variable or as a value for any property.
Keeping your password in plain text on the client machine RAM is a security no-no.

`SecurePassword` cannot be done with bindings.

> .NET documentation explains why the PasswordBox was not made bindable in the first place.

An alternative solution is to put the `PasswordBox` in your `ViewModel`public class LoginViewModel

```
public class LoginViewModel
{
   // other properties here

   public PasswordBox Password
   {
      get { return m_passwordBox; }
   }

   // Executed when the Login button is clicked.
   private void LoginExecute()
   {
      var password = Password.SecurePassword;

      // do more stuff...
   }
}
```

Yes, you are violating ViewModel best practices here, but

1. best practices are "recommendations that work well in most cases"
   rather than strict rules and
2. writing simple, easy-to-read, maintainable code and avoiding
   unnecessary complexity is also one of those "best practice" rules
   (which might be violated slightly by the "attached property"
   workaround).

Comment: So basically it doesn't work to bind the SecurePassword? Not even with an AttachedProperty or a Behavior?

Comment: @Knerd Yes, you can't.

Comment: @III so if I replace Password with SecurePassword it should work, I guess.

Comment: @Knerd No, you create a wrapper property which is `BoundPassword`.

Comment: ok, I tried and it doesn't work with the `SecurePassword`. I kinda don't want to use the plaintext version but it seems like I have to. Or is there a way to solve it with the `SecurePassword`?

Comment: @Knerd No, can't do binding with my alternative solution too. You'll really have to do the first solution I suggested. It's just a wrapper property though not direct.

Comment: crap, than I think I gonna do the code behind solution. I hoped it might work with behaviors :/

Comment: @Knerd Like I said, security issues. The `PasswordBox` doesn't have `DependencyProperties` in it. In order for binding to work you need dependency properties.

Comment: I know, the `Password` property comes from my `ViewModel`. So I am basically binding the `TargetPassword` to a property of my `ViewModel`. In my `Behavior` I use the `SecurePassword` property from the `PasswordBox` and assign it to the `TargetPassword` and there something needs to go wrong.

Comment: @lll I have asked this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26200799/put-a-view-control-in-its-viewmodel, because I don't know how to put the `PasswordBox` in my `ViewModel`.