# Put a View Control in its ViewModel

Tags: c#, mvvm, windows-runtime

I'm developing a Windows 8.1 Store app with C# and .Net Framework 4.5.1.

I'm trying to bind Password.SecurePassword to a ViewModel, and reading this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23020395/68571) I found a way to do it: Put the `PasswordBox` in my `ViewModel`.

But I don't know how to do it. I know how to bind Dependency Properties, but I don't know how to put that control on my ViewModel. This is my XAML:

```
<Page
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    DataContext="{Binding MainViewModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <PasswordBox x:Name="userPassword" />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

What do I have to do?

Comment: The post you link to describers the specific problem for `PassWord` (it's not a DP) and a solution. It's not going to be easier than that.

Comment: maybe that post will help 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483892/how-to-bind-to-a-passwordbox-in-mvvm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several options but I'll just give you the basic option without third party libraries.

In your `Page` constructor. You can do something like this.

```
public Page()
{
  var mainViewModel = this.DataContext as MainViewModel;
  if(mainViewModel != null)
  {
    mainViewModel.PasswordBox = userPassword;
  }
}
```

You can also set it on the `Loaded` event of the `View` and set the `PasswordBox` to the **ViewModel**.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Here, http://stackoverflow.com/a/4649830/68571, I have found how to do it. Thanks.

Comment: @VansFannel If you're gonna use `CommandParameters` just to pass the `PasswordBox` to the ViewModel. I'll just use `Behaviors`'s on Attach/Dettach to pass it to the `ViewModel`. I find it more cleaner and readable.